# RewriteRule not working, mod_rewrite installed/loaded on Apache2 Debian Lenny

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, debian-lenny, rewrite

This is my first time setting up my own linux server. I am migrating from shared hosting to my own cloud. mod_rewrite and mod_proxy are loaded.

I know for sure what I have in my htaccess worked on my old host, but doesn't on my linux server.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# This works
RewriteRule index.php / [L,R=301]

# This works
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php 

# This doesn't work
RewriteRule ^help/([^/]+)/$ /help.php?page=$1
```

What gives?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Rewrite ^help/(.+)/$ /help.php?page=$1
```

When accessing try:

```
http://domain.com/help/testingpage/
```

It should work.

P.S. domain.com/help/testingpage != domain.com/help/testingpage/

Comment: Still doesn't work. http://domain.com/help/testingpage/ goes to http://domain.com/help/ so does http://domain.com/help/anythingelse/